# How to Retrieve saved Session in windows phone 8 in side a (ExampePage.xaml.cs)

Tags: c#, facebook, xaml, session, windows-phone-8

I have saved the session using a method in a class called SessionService

```
    /// <summary> 
/// The service session. 
/// </summary> 
public class SessionService : ISessionService 
{ 
    private readonly IApplicationSettingsService _applicationSettings; 
    private readonly IFacebookService _facebookService; 
    private readonly IMicrosoftService _microsoftService; 
    private readonly IGoogleService _googleService; 
    private readonly ILogManager _logManager; 

    /// <summary> 
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SessionService" /> class. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="applicationSettings">The application settings.</param> 
    /// <param name="facebookService">The facebook service.</param> 
    /// <param name="microsoftService">The microsoft service.</param> 
    /// <param name="googleService">The google service.</param> 
    /// <param name="logManager">The log manager.</param> 
    public SessionService(IApplicationSettingsService applicationSettings, 
        IFacebookService facebookService, 
        IMicrosoftService microsoftService, 
        IGoogleService googleService, ILogManager logManager) 
    { 
        _applicationSettings = applicationSettings; 
        _facebookService = facebookService; 
        _microsoftService = microsoftService; 
        _googleService = googleService; 
        _logManager = logManager; 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// Gets the session. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <returns>The session object.</returns> 
    public Session GetSession() 
    { 
        var expiryValue = DateTime.MinValue; 
        string expiryTicks = LoadEncryptedSettingValue("session_expiredate"); 
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(expiryTicks)) 
        { 
            long expiryTicksValue; 
            if (long.TryParse(expiryTicks, out expiryTicksValue)) 
            { 
                expiryValue = new DateTime(expiryTicksValue); 
            } 
        } 

        var session = new Session 
        { 
            AccessToken = LoadEncryptedSettingValue("session_token"), 
            Id = LoadEncryptedSettingValue("session_id"), 
            ExpireDate = expiryValue, 
            Provider = LoadEncryptedSettingValue("session_provider") 
        }; 

        _applicationSettings.Set(Constants.LoginToken, true); 
        _applicationSettings.Save(); 
        return session; 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// The save session. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="session"> 
    /// The session. 
    /// </param> 
    private void Save(Session session) 
    { 
        SaveEncryptedSettingValue("session_token", session.AccessToken); 
        SaveEncryptedSettingValue("session_id", session.Id); 
        SaveEncryptedSettingValue("session_expiredate", session.ExpireDate.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); 
        SaveEncryptedSettingValue("session_provider", session.Provider); 
        _applicationSettings.Set(Constants.LoginToken, true); 
        _applicationSettings.Save(); 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// The clean session. 
    /// </summary> 
    private void CleanSession() 
    { 
        _applicationSettings.Reset("session_token"); 
        _applicationSettings.Reset("session_id"); 
        _applicationSettings.Reset("session_expiredate"); 
        _applicationSettings.Reset("session_provider"); 
        _applicationSettings.Reset(Constants.LoginToken); 
        _applicationSettings.Save(); 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// The login async. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="provider"> 
    /// The provider. 
    /// </param> 
    /// <returns> 
    /// The <see cref="Task"/> object. 
    /// </returns> 
    public async Task<bool> LoginAsync(string provider) 
    { 
        Exception exception = null; 
        try 
        { 
            Session session = null; 
            switch (provider) 
            { 
                case Constants.FacebookProvider: 
                    session = await _facebookService.LoginAsync(); 
                    break; 
                case Constants.MicrosoftProvider: 
                    session = await _microsoftService.LoginAsync(); 
                    break; 
                case Constants.GoogleProvider: 
                    session = await _googleService.LoginAsync(); 
                    break; 
            } 
            if (session != null) 
            { 
                Save(session); 
            } 

            return true; 
        } 
        catch (InvalidOperationException e) 
        { 
            throw; 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            exception = ex; 
        } 
        await _logManager.LogAsync(exception); 

        return false; 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// The logout. 
    /// </summary> 
    public async void Logout() 
    { 
        Exception exception = null; 
        try 
        { 
            var session = GetSession(); 
            switch (session.Provider) 
            { 
                case Constants.FacebookProvider: 
                    _facebookService.Logout(); 
                    break; 
                case Constants.MicrosoftProvider: 
                    _microsoftService.Logout(); 
                    break; 
                case Constants.GoogleProvider: 
                    _googleService.Logout(); 
                    break; 
            } 
            CleanSession(); 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            exception = ex; 
        } 
        if (exception != null) 
        { 
            await _logManager.LogAsync(exception); 
        } 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// Loads an encrypted setting value for a given key. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="key"> 
    /// The key to load. 
    /// </param> 
    /// <returns> 
    /// The value of the key. 
    /// </returns> 
    private string LoadEncryptedSettingValue(string key) 
    { 
        string value = null; 

        var protectedBytes = _applicationSettings.Get<byte[]>(key); 
        if (protectedBytes != null) 
        { 
            byte[] valueBytes = ProtectedData.Unprotect(protectedBytes, null); 
            value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(valueBytes, 0, valueBytes.Length); 
        } 

        return value; 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// Saves a setting value against a given key, encrypted. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="key"> 
    /// The key to save against. 
    /// </param> 
    /// <param name="value"> 
    /// The value to save against. 
    /// </param> 
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"> 
    /// The key or value provided is unexpected. 
    /// </exception> 
    private void SaveEncryptedSettingValue(string key, string value) 
    { 
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) 
        { 
            byte[] valueBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value); 

            // Encrypt the value by using the Protect() method. 
            byte[] protectedBytes = ProtectedData.Protect(valueBytes, null); 
            _applicationSettings.Set(key, protectedBytes); 
            _applicationSettings.Save(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

My Session Class is as follows :

```
using System;

namespace AuthenticationSample.WP80.Services.Model
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The session.
    /// </summary>
    public class Session
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the access token.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The access token.
        /// </value>
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the id.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The id value.
        /// </value>
        public string Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the expire date.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The expire date.
        /// </value>
        public DateTime ExpireDate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the provider.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The provider.
        /// </value>
        public string Provider { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need to get the session details  in the following page AllEvents.xaml.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using AuthenticationSample.WP80.ViewModel;
using AuthenticationSample.WP80.Services.Model;
using AuthenticationSample.WP80.Services;
using AuthenticationSample.WP80.Resources;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AuthenticationSample.WP80.Views
{
    public partial class AllEvents : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        public AllEvents()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            MainViewModels FakeData = new MainViewModels();
            FakeData.LoadData();
            DataContext = FakeData;



        }



    }
}
```

How can i  get the session details like AccessToken , Provider etc  in the above page?
I need this value here , how can i get the values here if i have already logged in?
g

Answer (score 0):

I tried to call the GetSession() Method in SessionService Class but it failed so  i tried to access it from phone application settings and it worked

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
            byte[] encryptedData  = (byte[])settings["session_token"];           
            byte[] valueBytes = ProtectedData.Unprotect(encryptedData, null);
            var  AccessToken  = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(valueBytes, 0, valueBytes.Length);
```